# What are the exact criteria for the example question on /about?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, tour

Moderators can choose an example question for the about page of their site. But we can't choose from all the questions, but only from a limited subset. This leads to the following situation on Skeptics, the full list of available questions is:

[image]

This isn't much of a choice, only a single question qualifies for the about page and that one is not really a good example for new users. A very good example for a Skeptics questions usually contains at least one link and a blockquote, and is often a bit longer.

I'd propose to change the criteria which restrict the available questions, but then I was unable to find those criteria in the first place and don't know which would have to be changed.

So what are the exact criteria for a question to be eligible for the about page?

Comment: One wonders why there needs to be criteria at all. It's a mod-only feature. It's not likely they're going to go rogue and pick something ridiculous.

Comment: @cod - there should be *some* criteria... Similar to the new dupe system - the post must have an accepted/upvoted answer for example...

Comment: Oh, @Lix. Don't bring *that* up with me. I haven't yet figured out why it's okay to continually post questions just because they haven't been answered yet.

Comment: @cod - I don't really follow what you're saying.

Comment: @lix I don't agree with the requirement that a question must have an answer in order to be a duplicate closure candidate. Down that path lies madness, being able to ask endless duplicate questions just because you haven't gotten an answer yet and no one can close them.

Comment: @cod - ahh.. yes.. I believe the requirement of an answered post was made to suit the provided text: "This question already has an answer here...". But I see what you mean now.

Comment: We have pages and pages and pages and pages of these questions on Stack Overflow. I'm curious what sort of criteria is being used as well.

Comment: That particular restriction doesn't apply when the dup and original have the same author, @Cody. Because yeah, re-posts are a pain. And the restrictions are in place because the fixed layout (and things like demonstrating voting, commenting and accept) demands certain properties; mods have fewer restrictions than the automatic selection, and there's an override to allow even less restriction on sites like Skeptics (which may or may not help; I'll have to check) at the cost of being somewhat ugly.

Comment: @Shog9 I'm aware it doesn't apply for the same author. But that doesn't really solve the problem. Lots of new users will re-ask a question because it doesn't have an answer. I can't mark those as duplicates. So what, I have to involve a moderator? So much for the community handling as much as possible. This is just close voting. You have to have these restrictions because of a fixed layout? What does that even mean? Because you have text that says "has an answer here"? Hmm, just take that out. The point is, the system is designed to encourage behavior we do not encourage.

Comment: At the time this was implemented, the situation you describe was very rare, @Cody. If you've observed a change to this, please post it up. Back to the topic at hand: the page we're talking about describes a question with two answers, one of them commented - at very least, the question has to have two answers with comments on one of them - otherwise, might as well use a fake question.

Comment: Fabian: I changed the settings on Skeptics - you should have a fairly decent pile of questions to choose from now, with the caveat that some/all of them will get cut off when displayed on the about page. I chose one that seemed reasonably not-bad; YMMV.